# How to keep a HTML popup in front in a chrome extension while page is reloading?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

So the chrome extension honey has a popup over the page injected by the contentscript that shows the current progress of applying coupons on a webshop.

Some websites reload as a whole if you submit a coupon (instead of just AJAX reqs), so if you would have injected some HTML it would go away because the contentscript would get reloaded and it would have to inject the HTML again.

See this as an example: https://youtu.be/iLk9Y5VUToE?t=87

How do they keep the popup in front at all times while a page is hard reloading while keeping track of the progress?

NOTE: This is not about the popup functionality (like popup.html)

Hope I explained this well enough :)

Comment: They may be using a separate utility. Or maybe they load the site in an iframe so their UI is shown in the embedding page as a DOM element. Either way, there's no magical method or API for extensions to show overlayed popups.

Comment: @wOxxOm Hmm it seems like they don't have an iframe. I was thinking, maybe they constantly send a message to the contentscript which injects the html? (like every 10ms). Would that be a possibility?

Comment: No, the simplest explanation is that they painted that in the video.